# Using Multiple Conditions in a Ruby IF statement

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use multiple conditions in an IF statement, to see if the number entered was 5, 10, or 15.  If the input is not one of these numbers, then it should output an error message.

But even if 5, 10, and 15 are input, it always outputs the error message.

```
when 3
  print("Enter the discount percentage, must be (5, 10, or 15)")
  dis= gets.to_i
  if (dis != 5 || dis != 10 || dis != 15)
    puts("You entered an invalid discount")
  else
  end
```

Comment: The correct method to get an integer from the beginning of a string would be [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i), not `_i`.

Comment: `p || q` is the same as `!(!p && !q)` (from De Morgan's Law). So your expression is the same as `!(dis == 5 && dis == 10 && dis == 15)`. The expression within the parentheses is obviously `false` for any value of `dis`, so `!(false) #=> true`, causing `puts` to be executed regardless of the value of `dis`.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct logic for your condition would be

```
if dis != 5 && dis != 10 && dis != 15
```

Because you want to print the error if the number is not 5, nor 10, nor 15.
A more cool way to write that is

```
if [5, 10, 15].all? { |i| dis != i }
```

Comment: or even `if [5, 10, 15].none? { |i| dis == i }`

Comment: Thanks for showing me 2 different ways of writing this and explaining why.  very much appreciate it.

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 2):

One could use[Enumerable#`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
puts ("You entered an invalid discount") unless [5,10,15].grep(dis).any?
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't seen that one before as i am still real new to this.  i will save that one for future use.

Comment: @pjs actually without `any?` it will not work (since empty array is truthy), so thanks for noticing!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko with `any?` you don't need `grep`, and it should be faster for larger lists because it can short circuit the search.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts ("You entered an invalid discount") unless [5,10,15].include?(dis)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way using regex:

```
puts "Enter discount, must be 5,10 or 15"
puts gets[/\A1?[05]\n\z/] ? 'Discount applied' : 'Invalid discount'
```